# MySql get count of categories in product search result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have a search result of the page, where those products appear which are searched by the user. I need a query which will give me a count of all the product's categories.

There are some conditions:

1. One product can have multiple categories.
2. There is one PRODUCT table:

   ```
   productId     productName
   1             corns
   2             Turmeric
   3             Cornetto
   ```

   one CATEGORIES table:

   ```
   catId       catName      ParentCategory
   101         Vegetable     111
   110         Chair         0
   111         Edible        0
   112         Table         0
   113         Rooms         0
   ```

   and one PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_RELATION

   ```
    id    productId     catId
    1     1             101
    2     1             111
    3     2             111
    4     3             111
   ```
3. The query which I am using for search result is:

   ```
   SELECT p.productName,
          GROUP_CONCAT(c.catId) as categoryid,
          GROUP_CONCAT(c.ParentCategory), 
          c.catName,
          c.Parent_Category 
   FROM Products p 
   LEFT JOIN `REL_Products__Categories` pc 
       ON pc.`productId` = p.`productId` 
   LEFT JOIN `Categories` c 
       ON pc.`catId` = c.`catId` 
   WHERE p.isActive = 1 
     AND p.Searchable = 1 
   GROUP BY p.record_number 
   HAVING (p.productName LIKE '%edible%' 
             OR p.Description LIKE '%edible%' 
             OR c.catName LIKE '%edible%)
   ```

This query is giving me results as follows:

```
productId   productName     categoryid     ParentCategory

1            corns            101,111      111,0

2            Turmeric         111          0

3            Cornetto         111          0
```

Now I need the above in this form:

```
Category Id    Count      Parent Id

101            1          111

111            3          0
```

Am I doing it in a wrong way, may be the first query's result can be customized so that I then I will be close to my final result. Please suggest that how I should do it.

Or is this achievable purely by Sql Query or I will need to use PHP loops in it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from those tables?

Comment: I wrote an answer base on your query and expect result, if that didn't hit your expect you can show some table data that will help us know your question more clearer

Comment: Thanks, also I have edited my question.

Comment: you can try my answer

Comment: In that query search result is missing, I need that searching query also, which will show results according to searched criteria by user.

Comment: just add it in `where`

Comment: Where is your description column in you sample data because I saw there is a condition about description but I didn't see in you sample data

Comment: Sorry, yes I missed that in sample data. Your solution worked, thanks :) I have up voted you.

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 1):

From your result and SQL I think you can try this.

just `JOIN` and `COUNT`, You condition can move to `WHERE` from `HAVING` because HAVING from aggregate function condition.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table Products(
   productId int,
   productName varchar(50)
);  




create table CATEGORIES (
   catId int,
   catName varchar(50),
   ParentCategory int
);  




insert into CATEGORIES  values (101,'Vegetable',111);
insert into CATEGORIES  values (110,'Chair',0);
insert into CATEGORIES  values (111,'Edible',0);
insert into CATEGORIES  values (112,'Table',0);
insert into CATEGORIES  values (113,'Rooms',0);


create table PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_RELATION(
   id int,
   productId int,
   catId int
);  

insert into Products values (1,'corns');
insert into Products values (2,'Turmeric');
insert into Products values (3,'Cornetto');

insert into PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_RELATION values (1,1,101);
insert into PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_RELATION values (2,1,111);
insert into PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_RELATION values (3,2,111);
insert into PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_RELATION values (4,3,111);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  pcr.catId,COUNT(*),c.ParentCategory
FROM 
Products p
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_RELATION pcr ON pcr.productId = p.productId
LEFT JOIN CATEGORIES c on c.catId = pcr.catId
GROUP BY pcr.catId,c.ParentCategory;

| catId | COUNT(*) | ParentCategory |
| ----- | -------- | -------------- |
| 101   | 1        | 111            |
| 111   | 3        | 0              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6pSHMEbsFFbmnRUS6nrD6w/0)